# How to get browser diagnostics

Tags: javascript, debugging, console.log

I'm adding a bug report form to my project. When the user hits the send button on the form (after they explain what the bug is) I am getting information of their browser automatically. I'm currently able to get their user-agent and the source code of the page, but I think it would be super useful if I could also get any errors that have been sent to the browser console.

I've googled for stuff like "javascript get console.log content" but haven't really found anything useful.

I read about creating a "wrapper" for window.log, and found this code:

```
window.log = function(){
  log.history = log.history || [];   // store logs to an array for reference
  log.history.push(arguments);
  if(this.console){
    console.log( Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments) );
  }
};
```

But it doesn't seem to be getting the errors that the browser (chrome) sends to the console.log.

Does anyone know how I can get ALL of the errors in the console.log?

Comment: The console is part of the browser. Which means you cannot grab the messages direct. You need to use a function that saves the message and then `console.log` it. Or you need a browser add-on.

Comment: I already have a function to replace using console.log, but I wanted to be able to get any errors that the browser sends as well. It's probably not possible, but it would be very useful information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seemed like an interesting idea. What I came up with is essentially a small JavaScript class that overrides the console's functions (but allows the default behavior - you can still see the information in Google Chrome's Inspector, for example).

It is pretty simple to use. Save this as 'consolelogger.js':

```
/**
 * ConsoleLogger
 *
 * Tracks the history of the console.
 * @author Johnathon Koster
 * @version 1.0.0
 */
var ConsoleLogger = function() {

    // Holds an instance of the current object.
    var _instance = this;

    this._logOverwrite = function(o) {

        var _log = o.log;

        // Overwrites the console.log function.
        o.log = function(e) {
            _instance.pushLog(e);
            // Calls the console.log function (normal browser behavior)
            _log.call(o, e);
        }

        // Overwrites the console.info function.
        o.info = function(e) {
            _instance.pushInfoLog(e);
            // Calls the console.info function (normal browser behavior)
            _log.call(o, e);
        }

        // Overwrites the console.warn function.
        o.warn = function(e) {
            _instance.pushWarnLog(e);
            // Calls the console.warn function (normal browser behavior)
            _log.call(o, e);
        }

        // Overwrites the console.error function.
        o.error = function(e) {
            _instance.pushErrorLog(e);
            // Calls the console.error function (normal browser behavior)
            _log.call(o, e);
        }

    }(console);

    // Holds the history of the console calls made by other scripts.
    this._logHistory = [];
    this._infoHistory = [];
    this._warnHistory = [];
    this._errorHistory = [];

    this._windowErrors = [];

    /**
     * This allows users to get the history of items not explicitly added.
     */
    window.onerror = function(msg, url, line) {
        _instance._windowErrors.push('Message: ' + msg + ' URL: ' + url + ' Line: ' + line);
    }

    /**
     * Adds an item to the log history.
     *
     * @param {log} object to log
     */
    this.pushLog = function(log) {
        this._logHistory.push(log);
    }


    /**
     * Adds an item to the information log history.
     *
     * @param {log} object to log
     */
    this.pushInfoLog = function(log) {
        this._infoHistory.push(log);
    }

    /**
     * Adds an item to the warning log history.
     *
     * @param {log} object to log
     */
    this.pushWarnLog = function(log) {
        this._warnHistory.push(log);
    }

    /**
     * Adds an item to the error log history.
     *
     * @param {log} object to log
     */
    this.pushErrorLog = function(log) {
        this._errorHistory.push(log);
    }

    /**
     * Returns the log history.
     * @this {ConsoleLogger}
     * @return {array} the log history.
     */
    this.getLog = function() {
        return this._logHistory;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the information log history.
     * @this {ConsoleLogger}
     * @return {array} the information log history.
     */
    this.getInfoLog = function() {
        return this._infoHistory;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the warning log history.
     * @this {ConsoleLogger}
     * @return {array} the warning log history.
     */
    this.getWarnLog = function() {
        return this._warnHistory;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the error log history.
     * @this {ConsoleLogger}
     * @return {array} the error log history.
     */
    this.getErrorLog = function() {
        return this._errorHistory;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the window log history.
     * @this {ConsoleLogger}
     * @return {array} the window log history.
     */
    this.getWindowLog = function() {
        return this._windowErrors;
    }

    /**
     * Returns all log histories.
     * @this {ConsoleLogger}
     * @return {array} the error log(s) history.
     */
    this.getLogHistory = function() {
        var _return = [];
        _return = this._logHistory
        _return = _return.concat(this._infoHistory);
        _return = _return.concat(this._warnHistory);
        _return = _return.concat(this._errorHistory);
        _return = _return.concat(this._windowErrors);
        return _return;
    }

}
```

And add it to your page like this:

```
<script src="consolelogger.js"></script>
<script>
// Create a new instance of ConsoleLogger
var logger = new ConsoleLogger;
</script>
```

Now, you don't have to do anything special to trap 'console.log', 'console.warn', 'console.info', or 'console.error'. The ConsoleLogger will do it for you, and allow you to get the history of what's been added.

To retrieve the history call these functions (all of them return a JavaScript array):

```
var logHistory = logger.getLog(); // Get the console.log history
var infoHistory = logger.getInfoLog(); // Get the console.info history
var warningHistory = logger.getWarnLog(); // Get the console.warn history
var errorHistory = logger.getErrorLog(); // Get the console.error history
var windowLog = logger.getWindowLog(); // Get the window error history

var allLogs = logger.getLogHistory(); // Returns all log histories as one array.
```

I apologize for such a lengthy post, but it seems to do the trick! I also created a [GitHub repo](https://github.com/paradoxonellc/ConsoleLogger); if I do any more work on it, changes will be committed there.

Comment: will this catch the errors the browser shows in the console? Not just whatever I would send to console.log myself, but errors generated because of coding errors?

Comment: Hello Charles! This will now catch messages you did not explicitly add using the console.* functions. Note, that in order for a message to be caught by this script, it has to be able to be caught by the window.onerror event.

Comment: So, it looks like all I needed from your script was the `window.onerror = function...` snippet, as I already have a logging system.

Comment: Hi @John, it seems that still doesn't catch some cases like Uncaught SyntaxError. Is it possible to catch any kind of error that shows on console?